# Rate limiting AMQP messages in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amqp

I've got an application that sends messages to a RabbitMQ cluster. If that cluster goes down for some reason, those events are buffered with the Bunny ruby gem. When that cluster goes up, all the buffered messages send at once, causing a massive increase in CPU load on the side publishing to RabbitMQ.

Is there some easy way to rate-limit the messages that get sent per second when the cluster goes back up, so they're only sent out at 100 messages per second or so?

The code I'm modifying is the logstash AMQP output plugin:

https://github.com/logstash/logstash/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/amqp.rb

Comment: Does anyone know where the code pertaining to what to do with messages that aren't able to be delivered lives? I'm trying to trudge through the ruby-amqp source and I'm a bit lost, as I'm not a ruby programmer unless absolutely forced to be. I'd be happy just knowing the section of the code to look at.